Do the Pitrs return home on Diwali?
I am looking for any scriptural reference stating that Pitrs return home to Pitrloka on Kartika Amavasya after the Mahalaya period, the ulkadana vrat is mentioned in the Skanda Purana (Karttikamasa-mahatmya, Vaishnava-khanda, 9.65-68) and eludes to them leaving on Diwali.

When the sun is in Libra, on the nights of Caturdaśī and new-moon day, men should celebrate the festival of “showing the path unto the Pitṛs” with firebrands in their hands. The dead men and ghosts who are in hell see the path, due to this Vrata always. No doubt need be entertained in this respect by leading sages.

